# Adding existing domain name to Wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, domain, domain-mapping

Can i redirect my domain to wordpress.com using my own nameserver?

Comment: Even though this is a couple of years old, it's still out-of-scope and off-topic. WPSE is not geared to support WordPress.com questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to redirect your users from `example.com` to `example.wordpress.com`, but really want `example.com` to be new domain name for your WordPress.com blog, you can [buy Domain Mapping for $12 per year](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/) if you already have your own domain.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just add 301 redirect rules using an htaccess file.

Comment: The question was about wordpress.com, there you can not edit the .htaccess file.